# Is there a CapitalizeFirstLetter method?

Tags: c#, .net, string

Is there a method to do that? Could it be done with an extension method?

I want to achieve this:

```
string s = "foo".CapitalizeFirstLetter();
// s is now "Foo"
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A simple extension method, that will capitalize the first letter of a string. As  Karl pointed out, this assumes that the first letter is the right one to change and is therefore not perfectly culture-safe.

```
public static string CapitalizeFirstLetter(this String input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) 
        return input;

    return input.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) +
        input.Substring(1, input.Length - 1);
}
```

You can also use [System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx).
The function will convert the first character of **each word** to upper case. So if your input string is `have fun` the result will be `Have Fun`.

```
public static string CapitalizeFirstLetter(this String input)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) 
         return input;

     return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(input);
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72831/how-do-i-capitalize-first-letter-of-first-name-and-last-name-in-c) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't find it searching

Comment: This still assumes that the first letter is the right one to change.  Not perfectly culture-safe yet.

Comment: first example will throw an exception if the string length is zero.  Should add "if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return input;" at the top.

Comment: Just one note: The CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(input);  will not work if the all letters in text are in uppercase,

Answer (score 10):

[System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx)

It has the advantage of being culture-safe.

Comment: After reading the remarks in the MSDN docs, it turns out this method just changes first letters to uppercase regardless of any real cultural details anyway.  +1 for pointing out obscure framework method, -1 for the specified method being misleading/broken.

Comment: Well the optimist would say that if you use it now, it may actually function as expected in the future. At any rate, it does exactly what was requested, and is built into the framework :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
static public string UpperCaseFirstCharacter(this string text) {
    return Regex.Replace(text, "^[a-z]", m => m.Value.ToUpper());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the text input can also be all in capitals.

I added a `ToLower` before the `ToTitleCase` is done:

```
    public static string CapitalizeFirstLetter(this string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        {
            return input;
        }

        return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(input.ToLower(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
    }
```