# Issue in capitalizing first letter of first name and last name

Tags: c#, .net, web

I am trying to capitalize the first letter of the first name, middle name and the last name. 
 I am trying to use **System.Globalization.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(newUser.Firstname)**  but i am getting an error in visual studio saying "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property". Help me with the solution for this:

```
public static UserAccount CreateUser(string firstName, string middleName, string lastName, string nameSuffix, int yearOfBirth, int? monthOfBirth, int? dayOfBirth, string email, string password, UserRole roles, bool tosAccepted = false)
{
    var newUser = new UserAccount
    {
        CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
        ActivationCode = Guid.NewGuid(),
        FirstName = firstName,
        MiddleName = middleName,
        LastName = lastName,
        NameSuffix = nameSuffix,
        YearOfBirth = yearOfBirth,
        MonthOfBirth = monthOfBirth,
        DayOfBirth = dayOfBirth,
        Email = email,
        UserRoles = roles,
        ToSAccepted = tosAccepted
    };
    string newUsers= System.Globalization.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(newUser.FirstName);
    newUser.SetPassword(password);
    return newUser;
}
```

Comment: RTFM, please. The documentation for ToTitleCase shows you how to use that method properly.

Comment: Well, I'm guessing OP got this from the accepted (and highly upvoted) answer to [How do I capitalize first letter of first name and last name in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72831/how-do-i-capitalize-first-letter-of-first-name-and-last-name-in-c?rq=1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ToTitleCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an instance method so you have to call it with a reference to an instance of `TextInfo`. You can get an instance of `TextInfo` from the current thread's culture like this:

```
var textInfo = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;
```

Or from a specific culture like this:

```
var textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US",false).TextInfo;
```

Also, it returns a new string rather than modifying the string that you pass in. Try something like this instead:

```
public static UserAccount CreateUser(string firstName, string middleName, string lastName, string nameSuffix, int yearOfBirth, int? monthOfBirth, int? dayOfBirth, string email, string password, UserRole roles, bool tosAccepted = false)
{
    var textInfo = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;

    var newUser = new UserAccount
    {
        CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
        ActivationCode = Guid.NewGuid(),
        FirstName = textInfo.ToTitleCase(firstName),
        MiddleName = middleName,
        LastName = textInfo.ToTitleCase(lastName),
        NameSuffix = nameSuffix,
        YearOfBirth = yearOfBirth,
        MonthOfBirth = monthOfBirth,
        DayOfBirth = dayOfBirth,
        Email = email,
        UserRoles = roles,
        ToSAccepted = tosAccepted
    };
    newUser.SetPassword(password);
    return newUser;
}
```

Comment: what if i need to add a period after the middle initial if only one
letter is entered in the field? Can i still use something similar

Comment: @NitinJaitely In that case, you can use something along the lines of `MiddleName = middleName + (middleName.Length == 1 ? "." : "")`—`?…:` is the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can call the [`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx) method to do this for you:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(lastName)
```