# How to capitalized first letter in Razor macro?

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco7

This is my first macro, I'm trying to make First letter of "@homeNode.Name" and "@page.Name" apear as upper case. Is there any method like adding ".ToUpper()" or ".ToLower()" to accomplish this?

This is macro code:

```
<nav>
<ul class="nav-list">
    @{ var homeNode = Model.AncestorOrSelf("about"); }

    <li class="@homeNode.Name @Library.If(homeNode.Id == Model.Id, "selected", "")"><a href="@homeNode.Url">@homeNode.Name</a></li>

    @foreach (var page in homeNode.Children.Where("Visible"))
    {
        var isSelected = false;
        if (Model.Id == page.Id || (Model.Parent != null && Model.Parent.Id == page.Id && Model.NodeTypeAlias != "Textpage"))
        {
            isSelected = true;
        }
        <li class="@page.Name @Library.If(isSelected, "selected")">
            <a href="@page.Url">@page.Name</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Use Use System.Globalization.TextInfo.ToTitleCase().  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72831/how-do-i-capitalize-first-letter-of-first-name-and-last-name-in-c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
System.Globalization.TextInfo.ToTitleCase();
```

Or just css

```
text-transform: capitalize;
```